# Is it possible to deploy a model on an offline storage device?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I've created a classification model, trained it and it is now ready for deployment.

The system where I want to deploy it consists of an Arduino that records some data. I want this to be fed into the classifier, and based on the output, I want my Arduino to perform some tasks. The system must function offline. I was wondering if it's possible to deploy the model into a storage device which can be queried by the Arduino, without requiring any connection to IBM Cloud?

Thanks

Comment: You can deploy models offline. You are not writing which Watson service you are using or if it is Watson Studio. Your "offline computer" needs to have the infrastructure to run the model.